# Syntax error only when applying filter

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access, I have a query built that at first glance looks like it does exactly what I want it to do, until I try to apply a filter. I built it in Design view, but the SQL statement is:

```
   SELECT tblTestCableDesign.ConnectorRefDes, 
          tblTestCableDesign.ConnectorPN, 
          DLookUp("[Type]","tblMMshells","[Code] = '" & LEFT([ConnectorPN],7) & "'") AS ShellType
     FROM (
          tblTestCablePNs 
    INNER 
     JOIN tblTestCables 
       ON tblTestCablePNs.[P/N] = tblTestCables.[P/N]) 
    INNER 
     JOIN tblTestCableDesign 
       ON tblTestCablePNs.[P/N] = tblTestCableDesign.[CablePN]
    WHERE (((LEFT([ConnectorPN],4)) LIKE "80#-"));
```

When I try to filter on my calculated field ShellType, I get the error:

> Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression '[Code] = ''805-00''

Again, I don't get any errors or #VALUES when the query runs, every record has the correct value from the lookup table. A couple of things I notice:

1. There is no syntax error in the expression given ("[Code] = '805-00'" is correct, though the `DlookUp` would return null.  I confirmed this my getting rid of my `LEFT` call and typing the string directly into the `DLookUp`
2. '805-00' is only six characters, not the 7 the `LEFT` calls for
3. I have another nearly identical query that runs fine, though the Where condition and P/N parsing is different.
4. This WAS working perfectly (well this part, at least) until I modified a record on my master table. All I did was change the ConnectorPN so it wouldn't show up in this query.

I'm at a loss here... Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Does your `ConnectorPN` have any `'` (single quote/apostrophe) in it?

Comment: ah ha. Not any that satisfied the 'WHERE' statement, but one in the master list. (The one I modified).  So am I to understand that the SQL runs the calculations on EVERY record prior to eliminating some based on the WHERE conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SunKnight0, I realized that one of the records in my table had a `'` in it. So the `Left` was actually returning the string `'805-00`. However, I don't know why this only caused an issue when filtering, and not when the query ran initially.